# authenticate a user in django pybb app

Tags: python, django, django-custom-user

I have successfully installed pybb app and all is good except the fact that I don't  how to 'tell' pybb app that a user has been authenticated by my main app. I'm using function based views and the normal **authenticate -> login** routine as described in the django documentation.
My authentication function looks like this:

```
def index_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user_name = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            person = authenticate(username=user_name, password=password)
            if person is not None:
                login(request, person)
                if request.user.is_authenticated:                    
                    return HttpResponseRedirect("/forum")
    form = LoginForm()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'loginform': form})
```

And my main urls.py has this included as per directed in the pybb documentation

```
url(r'^forum/', include('pybb.urls', namespace='pybb'))
```

I can verify that a user has been authenticated before I do the `HttpResponseRedirect("/forum")`  but that seems to get lost once the pybb app is loaded . I just don't know where I should start looking into. Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Try using django-allauth. Its quite easy and better